# WPF MainWindow Loaded

Tags: wpf, mainwindow

Which event is triggered in the MainWindow when it now SHOWN and VISIBLE?
When I try showing a dialog in the Loaded event, the window would still not be fully loaded/visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `IsVisibleChanged` event:

```
    private void MainWindow_OnIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool) e.NewValue == true)
        {
            //DO Stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think i now understand whats happening. The MainWindow IS LOADED and IS SHOWN, BUT....the child controls like the menus and toolbars are not yet shown....so how do i check that EVERYTHING is now loaded and visible ?

Comment: why do you want it? may be there is some other elegant way of achieving it

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by listening for the `ContentRendered` event instead.